# WPF DataBinding, MVVM and Routed Events

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, inversion-of-control

When I try to call my UserControl's custom RoutedEvent in my XAML using a Command Delegate binding I get this exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll 
Additional information: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' threw an exception.'
```

My WPF application is using MVVM and IOC so all the logic is in the view models.

The DataContext for a view is set in a resource dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:MyApp.Order.View"
            xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyApp.Order.ViewModel">

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:OrderViewModel}">
    <vw:OrderView />
</DataTemplate>
```

etc

I have a UserControl in another project within this solution that happens to be a Keyboard and I've wired up a routed event like so:

```
public partial class MainKeyboard : UserControl
{
    public static DependencyProperty TextProperty;
    public static DependencyProperty FirstLetterToUpperProperty;

    // Create a custom routed event by first registering a RoutedEventID
    // This event uses the bubbling routing strategy
    public static readonly RoutedEvent TapEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "Tap", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, 
        typeof(RoutedEventHandler), 
        typeof(MainKeyboard));

    // Provide CLR accessors for the event
    public event RoutedEventHandler Tap
    {
        add { AddHandler(TapEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(TapEvent, value); }
    }

    // This method raises the Tap event
    void RaiseTapEvent()
    {
        RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(MainKeyboard.TapEvent);
        RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
    }
```

Now, when I consume this event using my XAML declration and bind the Command to the view model's command delegate like I normally do:

```
  <assets:MainKeyboard           Tap="{Binding DoTapCommandInViewModel}" />
```

I get an error, but I can do this everywhere else, like in a button right above this code:

```
  <Button Content="GetStarted" 
                            Command="{Binding DoTapCommandInViewModel}" 
                            Style="{StaticResource GetStartedButton}" />
```

What does work for me is calling a method in the code behind of this XAML file:

```
<assets:MainKeyboard Tap="MainKeyboard_OnTap"/>
```

The datacontext for both the button and the keyboard user control are the same; they live in the same view.

So why can't I bind this event directly to a command?

Comment: You can bind `DoTapCommandInViewModel` to `Button.Command`, right? What is the `DataContext` of that `Button`? You cannot bind `Command` directly to event, but e.g. use `EventTrigger` and `InvokeCommandAction` instead.

Comment: Thank you @dytori that worked. I will post my solution - an EventTrigger was the key! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dytori was right; I needed an Event Trigger on the control declaration. Ah Wpf...

```
           <assets:MainKeyboard>
                    <b:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <b:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                            <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DoTapTapTap}"/>
                        </b:EventTrigger>
                    </b:Interaction.Triggers>
            </assets:MainKeyboard>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but another solution is to create a new dependency property of type `ICommand` on your `MainKeyboard`, bind your command that you want to call on that dependency property, and create a method in your code-behind that calls the `Execute()` method of that command.

- Create dependency property of type `ICommand` in `MainKeyboard` and code-behind method that calls command:

```
public partial class MainKeyboard : UserControl
{
    //dependency property of ICommand
    public static DependencyProperty TapCmdProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TapCmd",
        ICommand,
        MainKeyboard,
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public ICommand TapCmd
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(TapCmdProperty);
        set { SetValue(TapCmdProperty, value); }
    }

    //method that calls Execute() on bound command
    private void MainKeyboard_OnTap(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TapCmd != null) TapCmd.Execute();
    }
}
```

- Bind command in ViewModel to `TapCmd` dependency property and call `Tap` routed event on code-behind method:

```
<assets:MainKeyboard TapCmd="{Binding DoTapCommandInViewModel}"
                     Tap="MainKeyboard_OnTap"/>
```

Comment: Only about 8 years late - I didn't know people were still using WPF in 2023...